# Docker expose a port only to localhost

Tags: docker, iptables

I want to restrict my database access to `127.0.0.1`, so I executed the following command:

```
docker run -it mysql:5.5 -p 127.0.0.1:3306:3306 -name db.mysql
```

But I have some confusion...

You can see here that only the port of `127.0.0.1` will be forwarded:

```
; docker ps
mysql:5.5     127.0.0.1:3306->3306/tcp   db.mysql
```

Interestingly, I cannot find this restriction in iptables:

```
; iptables -L
Chain FORWARD (policy DROP)
DOCKER     all  --  anywhere             anywhere

Chain DOCKER (2 references)                                                                                                                                                                  
target     prot opt source               destination
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             192.168.112.2        tcp dpt:mysql
```

The source of this rule is `anywhere`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The incoming traffic will go as next:

```
Incoming package to host's network -> use ip tables to forward to container
```

And, your restrict was not in iptables, it was in host's network, you just open `3306` bind on `127.0.0.1`, not `0.0.0.0`, so you of course not see anything in iptables. `127.0.0.1:3306:3306` means `hostIp:hostPort:containerPort`.

You could confirm it with `netstat -oanltp | grep 3306` to see no `0.0.0.0` was there, so no foreign host could visit your host machine, thus also could not visit your container.